# Get IP address from within Nutch plugin

Tags: java, nutch

I'm working on a project where we are crawling and indexing several websites. For this I am using Apache Nutch 2.3. Now we would also like to index the servers IP address. After searching the documentation I have concluded that Nutch seems to be unable to do this out of the box. For this reason I am now trying to write a plugin that implements this feature.

The problem I am running into is that I am unable to get the IP address from within the plugin. For my test I've written the following code:

```
@Override
public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, String url, WebPage page) throws IndexingException {
    ByteBuffer ip = page.getMetadata().get("_ip_");
    System.out.println("IP address is " + Bytes.toString(ip));
```

I would expect Nutch to print the server's IP address, but instead the IP address is always null. Does anyone know how to get the server IP address from within the plugin?

Some notes:

- There is a setting called "store.ip.address". I've set this to true, but it makes no difference.
- In the master repository a geoip plugin is available, which gets the IP address in a similar way. So I think it should be possible, though it is a different version of Nutch.
- I would rather not modify the source of Nutch itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution by making two changes in the nutch-site.xml config file:

- use protocol-http instead of protocol-httpclient
- Set the httpclient store.ip.address to true

Answer (score 0):

> Try this if it can help..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(myip);
</script>
```